# Bring my app to the foreground in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

My app has to run for a long time (also) in the background, due to Location Services.
When a certain condition is met the app has to move to the foreground.
I was able to run my app in the background and bring it to the front manually.
Reading up on this issue I got confused on how to move my app to the foreground by code.

It has to be in an if statement but what to do from here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No do not think this is possible. You will be able to spawn a `UILocalNotification` to show application state to the user, but it is my understanding that iOS prevents you from making your app take focus.

Comment: Notification is the ideal solution.

Comment: Notification works, thanks for that, but I really want to show an AlertView and play an AlarmSound (as in the clock app). Can you help me out?

Comment: @AdriOosterwijk That's another question, you should accept this answer if it addresses the initial question.

Comment: Whether an alert view is shown or not depends on the users notification options in Settings. The Clock app overrides those defaults, I believe, in a way that third-party apps cannot.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I understand that I have to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do that without user interaction. You can present a UILocalNotification 

-- you can't even be *sure* iOS leaves it running though!

on a jailbroken phone I guess it is possible

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly not possible, as it would be a mess if any app could just take over control at any point in time. As mentioned, you have to post a notification, and then it is up to the user if he or she wants to launch the app. If you notification states a good reason why they should launch your app, they might very well do it :-) And remember, don't mix up the user's needs with your/your app's needs.

Comment: Sure, the user has always the upperhand. However, this app is a sort of alarm app. It has to generate an alarm when a certain distance is covered. It should even wake people from their sleep. So, notifications is a great option if I'm able to present the user with an AlertView dialog and a firm alarmsound. Any help is most apreciated.